# Does anyone know what this onomatopoeia means?

Tags: onomatopoeia, anime

So, I watch a lot of anime but one scene in an anime called "Jojo's Bizarre Adventure" uses onomatopoeia very often, I'm trying to find out the meaning of this one in particular

[image: The Awaken My Masters Thing.]

(I don't know much about the Japanese language.)

I tried looking it up on multiple different platforms but no luck. I'm trying to find out so I can understand the meaning in an upcoming project of mine. I can't even tell if this is kanji!

Answer (score 4):

It's ドドン, a variant of [ドン](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%89%E3%83%B3-1). Something like this is very common in manga, but here katakana is used as a visual effect in anime?